# Extracts marks of all students in class from website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This code extracts marks of all students in class and stores the result in a file results.txt, using BeautifulSoup. I'm looking for code review and suggestions.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

file = open("results.txt","w")

for roll in range(1,60):
    if roll in range(1,10):
            rollstr = '0'+str(roll)
    else:
            rollstr = str(roll)
    url = 'http://www.*.org/'
    r = requests.get(url)

    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    file.write('roll: ' +rollstr + ' ')

    for i in soup.find_all('strong'):
            sgpa = i.get_text()
            if sgpa.find('SGPA') == 0:
                    file.write(sgpa)
                    break
    file.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

Your code looks good but you might like to know that there is a [Style Guide for Python Code called PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). If you are interested, you'll find tools to check your code automatically ([pep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8)) and to fix it ([autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8/1.1.1)).

In your case, I can see straight-away that you are sometimes missing spaces around your '+' operator.

**String format**

You'll find [various more pythonic ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118071/python-add-leading-zeroes-using-str-format) to format your number with leadings 0s.

Also, in case you want to keep your current logic, comparison can be written pretty succintly in Python so that you can simply write : `if 1 <= roll < 10`. (Please note that in Python 2.x, `range` returns a list so checking `if x in range(whatever)` is not efficient in time (it has to check all elements if the elements you are looking for is not in the list) nor in memory (a list is built for no reason)).

**Using context managers**

Opening files and remembering to close them is a bit tedious. Good thing is that Python has a clean solution to this : the [`with` keyword](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). In a nutshell, you use `with` when you open your file, you add a level of indentation and the magic to close your file will happen automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

Couple web-scraping and HTML-parsing related notes:

- since you are issuing multiple requests and to the same domain, instantiate a [web-scraping `requests.Session` object](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) and re-use to make requests - this would provide a performance boost since all the requests in the same session would *re-use the same TCP connection to the host*
- when you instantiate a `BeautifulSoup` class, you should specify what parser `BeautifulSoup` needs to be using under-the-hood:

  ```
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
  # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
  # soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html5lib")
  ```

  Otherwise, it would pick one automatically based on the installed packages in this particular Python environment. This may lead to `BeautifulSoup` picking up different parser on different machines or Python environments which would make your script unstable, behaving differently on different machines. See more at [Installing a Parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) and [Differences Between Parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)